# Selecting a cell in UITableView another one gets affected

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, uitableview

When I select a cell in an `UITableView` I change its image, but a cell out of sight (need to scroll down to see the affected cell) gets affected which means that the affected cell also change its image. It must be something about the reused cells, but I can't figured out why and how to solve this problem. Hope you guys can help me, thank you.

Another thing is, the cell should not reset its image when it get scroll out of sight.

Here is my delegates for the `UITableView`:

```
//UITableview delegate
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return Arecipe.IngredientArr.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if (tableView == IngrediensTableView) {
        print("Cell")

        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")

        let ingredient = self.Arecipe.IngredientArr[indexPath.row]

        if ((cell == nil)) {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
            cell!.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "Ingr_Uncheck")
        }

        cell!.textLabel?.text = ingredient.UnitValue + " " + ingredient.UnitName + " " + ingredient.Name
        cell!.selectionStyle = .None

        return cell!
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("Row \(indexPath.row) selected")

    if (tableView == IngrediensTableView) {
        let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!

        print(cell.textLabel?.text)

        if(cell.imageView?.image == UIImage(named: "Ingr_Uncheck")) {
            cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "Ingr_Check")
        } else {
            cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "Ingr_Uncheck")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i had similar problem with this..if time you need to see NSCache if not use this library "sdwebimage "..this will do all things for you..keeping all the images in the document directory and reusing it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the affected cell also change its image. It must be something about the reused cells

That's right! The reason is that you set `Ingr_Uncheck` image only to a brand-new cell. If a cell gets reused, you skip setting the image, keeping whatever was set there previously.

The decision to set `Ingr_Check` vs. `Ingr_Uncheck` image needs to be done based on the state of your table's model.

```
if(myCodeThatChecksIfRowIsChecked(indexPath.row)) {
    cell!.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "Ingr_Check")
} else {
    cell!.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "Ingr_Uncheck")
}
```

Now the proper image is set to both new and reused cells, making sure that reusing a previously checked cell does not change the visuals.

The code `myCodeThatChecksIfRowIsChecked` needs to rely on some stored state that you change inside your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method. This is where you need to maintain a list of row numbers for cells that have been checked. This is also the list that you consult to decide if a cell should be unchecked or not: doing it based on the image is not the correct approach.

Comment: thank you for your reply. Sorry I didn't not mention this in my question, but doing what you say will reset the cell's image when it gets scroll out of sight, but I need the cell to hold its image even when it is out of sight.

Comment: @LocDaiLe I see. Please see the edit. The fix is slightly more complex - you need to have code that, given the row number, can determine if the user has checked it or not. For that to work you need to keep the checked/unchecked state somewhere (in your model). Look at that state inside your `myCodeThatChecksIfRowIsChecked` function to make the decision.

Comment: So you are saying i need an array to keep track of which cells is selected or not?

Comment: @LocDaiLe It could be an array, but it does not have to be an array. It has to be some sort of collection - a list, a dictionary, an array, a bit vector, and so on.

Comment: Hi @dasblinkenlight. I tried to make an array with NSIndexPath, and for each time I select a cell I append it to the array, and in the cellForRowAtIndexPath I check if the current indexpath is in the array and change image.

Comment: @LocDaiLe It's not enough to append checked cells to the array, you also need to remove un-checked cells from it. Basically, this will replace your current `if(cell.imageView?.image == UIImage(named: "Ingr_Uncheck"))` logic in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method. `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` will check if the path is on the list or not. If it is on the list of checked items, remove it and use `Ingr_Uncheck`. Otherwise, add it and use `Ingr_Check`

Answer (score 1):

u cant compare 2 uiimage by "=="

```
if(cell.imageView?.image == UIImage(named: "Ingr_Uncheck"))
```

use this

```
if( [UIImagePNGRepresentation(cell.imageView?.image) isEqual:UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIImage(named: "Ingr_Uncheck"))] == YES)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply @vaibby, but comparing two uiimages work fine. The image gets change when selecting the cell.

Comment: @vaibby, I dont agree with you. you can compare with "==" it will check for both instance are same or not. Probably that is not what you need

Comment: i know this code is not much helpfull enough but I said about comparing 2 UIImage. what @LocDaiLe much do is take self.Arecipe.IngredientArr.UnitCheck and check if it is checked or not

Answer (score 0):

You could resolve this in two ways. Either set the image to `nil` `cellForRow`

```
cell.imageView?.image = nil
```

Or if you have custom class for the cell, implement

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    imageView?.image = nil

 }
```

Reset with nil or with the default image